# Flask server can't read cyrillic requests

Tags: python, flask, character-encoding

Here is my simple endpoint:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    print(request.data)
    return Response("", mimetype='application/json')
```

The request body is:

```
"тест"
```

And the server prints `b'"\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82"'` for request data.

How to set appropriate charset, providing content type header did nothing?

Also is there a way to get rid of that annoying `b` at the start of every request body?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.get_data

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having similar problem:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Response
from flask import reques
import chardet

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    charset = chardet.detect(request.data)['encoding']
    print(request.data.decode(charset))
    return Response("", mimetype='application/json')
```

I was unable to make flask to this for me...
so you have to manually decode the bytes.

Comment: But this is wrong. You should fix 1- the encoding. You should know what kind of encoding you are expecting, 2- the request data should be correctly formed. (so no `request.data`). Your file is not json. You "lie" and you pretend that computer will do the correct thing?